# Unicorn workers dying for no reason

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nginx, unicorn

All the unicorn workers are dying silently, no indication as to why, and I can't find any evidence of an external process killing them.  I'm new to diagnosing this kind of stuff, and after several hours of research, experimenting, and trying to figure this out, I'm at a dead end.

Background info- it's a Rails 4.1 app, Ruby 2.0, running nginx and unicorn on a Ubuntu 14.04 server.

**unicorn.rb**

```
working_directory "/home/deployer/apps/ourapp/current"
pid "/home/deployer/apps/ourapp/current/tmp/pids/unicorn.pid"
stderr_path "/home/deployer/apps/ourapp/current/log/unicorn.log"
stdout_path "/home/deployer/apps/ourapp/current/log/unicorn.log"

listen "/tmp/unicorn.ourapp.sock"
worker_processes 2
timeout 30
```

**excerpt from unicorn.log (last lines before it dies and after restart)**

```
I, [2016-08-28T19:54:01.685757 #19559]  INFO -- : worker=1 ready
I, [2016-08-28T19:54:01.817464 #19556]  INFO -- : worker=0 ready
I, [2016-08-29T09:19:14.818267 #30343]  INFO -- : unlinking existing socket=/tmp/unicorn.ourapp.sock
I, [2016-08-29T09:19:14.818639 #30343]  INFO -- : listening on addr=/tmp/unicorn.ourapp.sock fd=10
I, [2016-08-29T09:19:14.818807 #30343]  INFO -- : worker=0 spawning...
I, [2016-08-29T09:19:14.824358 #30343]  INFO -- : worker=1 spawning...
```

**Some pertinent info:**

- After a period of time ranging from about 8 - 20 hours, unicorn dies.
- There's no error recorded in the unicorn log.
- I searched all of `/var/log` for evidence of processes that were killed, and can only find one unrelated process that was killed a few days ago.
- New Relic shows flat memory usage before the last random shutdown, with ruby using around 400mb.  It's currently at 480mb with no problems, so I don't think it's hitting memory constraints.
- Same with CPU usage...ruby was hovering around 0.1% before it died.
- The last couple of times it died were in the middle of the night.  The only requests coming in were from New Relic and Linode Longview monitoring.
- Our production.log shows a last request before dying as a ping from New Relic.  It `Completed 200 OK in 264ms` so it doesn't seem to be a request timing out.
- It's happening in staging as well, and the log level is set to debug, and there are no additional clues in the staging logs.

**Questions:**

- What could be killing the Unicorn workers that's not the out-of-memory manager or a shut down signal?
- Could it be the OOM or a shut down signal, and it's being recorded in some place that I'm not looking, or just not being recorded for some reason?
- Is there a way to capture what's happing to Unicorn in more detail?

I have no idea where to go from here, so any suggestions would be much appreciated.

**UPDATE**

As suggested, I used strace to find out that unicorn was being killed by an old crontab (I know I should have checked there earlier) added by the previous developers that was intended to restart the server every night.  The stop command worked, but the start command was failing.

I still don't know why I wasn't able to find anything in my log searches, but after attaching strace to the main unicorn process (using something like `strace -o /tmp/strace.out -s 2000 -fp <unicorn_process_id>`), the strace log ended with a clear  `+++ killed by SIGKILL +++`.  I searched the logs again, and that led me to the crontab.

The underlying cause is probably pretty specific to my situation, but I'm *really* glad I know about strace now.

Comment: strace to the rescue!

Comment: @jedifans Thanks, I looked up a couple articles on that and it looks promising!

Comment: @elements: Mysterious! Please, let us know what you find with strace :)

Comment: @kiddorails I definitely will!

Comment: @elements Do you have an update regarding this? This is also my problem right now. Thanks!

Comment: @MeriAlvarado Hi, I updated my question, but I'm not sure how much help it will be to anyone else.